# Display configuration isn't saved on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, kde5

I have 3 monitors, one connected via DisplayPort and two — via HDMI.

When X session starts, the displays are messed up. So I open Display Configuration and order them properly. However, it isn't saved.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-14-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 62,7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
```

Any ideas the configuration isn't being saved?

Information about my displays:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6400 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+4480+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   ...
DP-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440    143.97*+ 120.00    99.95    59.95  
   ...
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   ...
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```